# Backend category tree slow - manage categories

Tags: category, backend, category-tree, management, slowbackend

Recently i have imported a good number of categories. But now whenever i go to the manage categories in the backend panel, it loads the page extremely slow.

It takes about 20-30 seconds to load the manage categories page, and about the same time when clicking on a desired category for it to load it's data or adding a new category.

Tried so far:

- Reindex all the data
- Made sure the server is well configured(memory,caching,ini,msql etc.)
- Tried the compiler
- Used the magento repair database tool to see if it gave any errors(none)
- Tried the same setup on a highend localhost server (without **any** plugins/extensions)

But the problem persists.

Some stats:
- About 250.000 different products
- About 1.2 million product-category relations
- About 200.000 different categories
- On a reliable and fast VPS server with a decent host (no cheap out of the box solution)
- Running on Nginx
- Flat catalog/products both enabled

Here's an output of magento's profiler on the manage categories page:
[image]

I'm not a pro so the only thing what gets my attention is the time and cnt values of mage, tree.phtml and catalog_Category_tree_ismovable. But i'm not sure what to do with this info.

If anyone knows an idea, can point me in the right direction or anything else helpful i would be very grateful!

If any information is missing from this post i'll be glad to add it if asked for.

Comment: is flat category and product data enabled in `System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Frontend` ?

Comment: Forgot to add that, yes. Flat category and products are both enabled.

Comment: i wonder if its a real shop or test ?? you just imported all from another platform to magento?

Comment: We are moving to magento from an old system. Yes, the categories have been imported. The same with all products and all other data (which does work properly). I don't really see the relevance of these questions?